# Script sends confirmation emails with attachments to all receipents, whenever triggered by only one

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms, google-workspace

The script systematically processes each response from the form, generating personalized documents and PDFs(Admission Form), which is shared via confirmation emails with attachments automating the creation and distribution of these documents.

But the when triggered by a new response by the onFormSubmit, the script starts all over again for all the entries. Thus creates same files multiple times(Wastes my cloud space) and moreover sends confirmation email to all the responders who have already received the same.

I figured out the problem is that my script cannot determine which of the entries have already been processed. Thus I added extra few lines to keep a track of processed data on to another spreadsheet. Which is also working fine

But I could not stop it from running it for all the enties when triggered

Here's the script

```
function generateDocsAndPDFsFromFormResponses() {
  var formId = '1htEcGvIcXJ6792kQj2KE3-5YN7FCIN2CaKaizPC2w9c';
  var templateId = '1pmFfQh34IE_fNEhI2zinHMEDjGopdXQovHiPurMA4U0';
  var formResponsesSheetId = '1DTkh8Y0o257MpD9EQSWTJQFLd8LZuYL2HLLN_p0E3Zk';
  var processedResponsesSheetId = '1Tx6Szv46jLo0zfNGV4u7tim8qGo1HBSE2qRE1L9fIW4';
  var targetFolderId = '1VOc8DcJIXu2yea4EdzAI6k7AT8oh3qcm';
  var pdfFolderId = '12pHuCvkgCzKgh14PDyhkMVZTrEqT5EL2';
  var docPrefix = 'TRHSS Admission Form ';

  // Creation of DOC File from Response Sheet & Template document and Save to AdmissionFormDOC Folder
  var form = FormApp.openById(formId);
  var templateDoc = DriveApp.getFileById(templateId);
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(targetFolderId);

  var formResponsesSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(formResponsesSheetId);
  var formResponses = formResponsesSheet.getSheetByName('Form Responses 1').getDataRange().getValues();

  // Assuming the first row contains the headers
  var headers = formResponses[0];
  var nameColumnIndex = headers.indexOf('Name of the Student');
  var contactColumnIndex = headers.indexOf('Contact Number');
  var dobColumnIndex = headers.indexOf('Date of Birth');
  var sessionColumnIndex = headers.indexOf('Admission Session');
  var seekedColumnIndex = headers.indexOf('Admission Seeked in');
  var emailColumnIndex = headers.indexOf('Email Address'); // Add this line for email

  // Step 2: Retrieve processed response IDs
  var processedResponsesSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(processedResponsesSheetId);
  var processedResponses = processedResponsesSheet.getSheetByName('Processed Responses 1');
  var processedResponseIds = processedResponses.getRange(2, 1, processedResponses.getLastRow() - 1, 1).getValues().flat();
  
  for (var i = 1; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
    var response = formResponses[i];
    var responseId = response[0]; // Assuming the response ID is in the first column
    
    // Step 3: Check for uniqueness using Google Forms' submission ID
    if (!processedResponseIds.includes(responseId)) {
      var studentName = response[nameColumnIndex];
      var contactNumber = response[contactColumnIndex];
      var dobValue = response[dobColumnIndex];
      var admissionSession = response[sessionColumnIndex];
      var admissionSeeked = response[seekedColumnIndex];
      var email = response[emailColumnIndex]; // Add this line for email

      var docName = docPrefix + "Session " + admissionSession + " " + admissionSeeked + " " + studentName + " - " + contactNumber;

      var newDoc = templateDoc.makeCopy(docName, folder);
      var doc = DocumentApp.openById(newDoc.getId());
      var body = doc.getBody();

      // Format Date of Birth into DD-MMM-YYYY format
      var dobDate = new Date(dobValue);
      var formattedDob = Utilities.formatDate(dobDate, "GMT", "dd-MMM-yyyy");

      for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
        var header = headers[j];
        var value = response[j] || ''; // Handle blank responses
        if (header === 'Date of Birth') {
          var dobDate = new Date(value);
          var formattedDob = Utilities.formatDate(dobDate, "GMT", "dd-MMM-yyyy");
          value = formattedDob;
        }
        body.replaceText("{{" + header + "}}", value);
      }

      doc.saveAndClose();

      // Convert the document to PDF
      var pdfBlob = DriveApp.getFileById(newDoc.getId()).getAs('application/pdf');
      var pdfFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(pdfFolderId); 
      var pdfFile = pdfFolder.createFile(pdfBlob.setName(docName + '.pdf'));
      
      // Send the PDF to the responder via email
      var subject = 'Your TRHSS Admission Form Submission';
      var message = 'Thank you for your submission. Attached is your admission form PDF.';
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message, {attachments: [pdfFile]});
      
      // Add the processed response ID to the list
      processedResponseIds.push(responseId);
      // Append the processed response ID to the 'Processed Responses 1' sheet
      processedResponses.appendRow([responseId]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Three things: 1) `don't use a loop`, 2) use an `event-driven trigger` [onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#event-driven_triggers) ("the one for Sheets if the form submits to a spreadsheet") that will trigger your script when a new submission is received; and 3) use `Event Objects` [doc ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#form-submit). This will identify the row on the sheet that was updated by the form submission details so that you can send your email for that row/submission and that row/submission only.

Comment: Did you resolve this?